# Why do I get 'permission denied' after using ./file2 in Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, centos, rhel

For example I have a file named `file2` that echoes something.

So in the shell, after typing this

```
# ./file2
```

It shows

> Permission denied

Where am I wrong here?

Comment: You're trying to execute a file that you don't have permission to.  Either your don't have the proper privileges or the file cannot be executed.

Comment: The duplicate is a duplicate of the question in your title - which is a different question from what you have in the question body.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to execute a file and you do not have the right permissions for this. When you create a new Bash script with your text editor (let's say Vim), you should have the following permissions: `-rw-r--r--`. As a user, you can then read and write this file, but you cannot execute it with `./`.

1. If you want to execute a file without changing permissions, you can use the following command: `bash myFile.sh`.
2. If you want to execute a file with `./`, you will have to modify permissions. Something like that is OK: `chmod +x myFile.sh`.
3. If you do not want to struggle with `./` and prefer to call `myFile.sh` from anywhere like other built-in commands, move the executable file in a directory that is in your PATH. `/usr/local/bin` should be a wise choice. Check your PATH with `echo $PATH`, just in case...

Comment: I'd suggest `$HOME/bin` is a better choice (by far) for random commands.  Only commands that might be useful to everyone on the machine belong in `/usr/local/bin`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks for your comment. You are perfectly right. I suggested `/usr/local/bin` for convenience, but using `$HOME/bin` is better. ;)

Answer (score 1):

`.` refers to the current working directory and `..` refers to the parent directory. So `./file2` means "execute the file named file2 in the current directory". Without the `./`, the shell will search for file2 in all the directories of your PATH. If you want to execute it, add the execute bit with `chmod +x ./file2` and try again. If you just want to view it, try `less ./file2`